# Router middleware not working properly in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on Nodejs and using "Express js", Right now i am working on "Router Middleware" function With following code,whenever i hit "http://localhost:3000" then "router middle" working/executed, but i want whenever i hit "http://localhost:3000/api/" (api route) only then "router middleware" should active/execute.Here is my current code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Create a router instance
const router = express.Router();

// Define a middleware function specific to the router
const routerMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  // Perform some operations on the request or response
  console.log('Router middleware executed');
  next();
};

// Apply the middleware to the router
router.use(routerMiddleware);

// Define a route on the router
router.get('/example', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello from the router');
});

// Mount the router on the app
app.use('/api', router);

// Start the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `router.use(routerMiddleware)` you can add middleware directly to router like this: `app.use('/api',routerMiddleware,router);`

Comment: but what is wrong with my code ? where i am wrong ?

Comment: In your code, you use `routerMiddleware` for the entire app. This means that the middleware will intercept and execute for any router that is accessed. If you intend to run middleware only for a specific router, in your case, you need to implement it as demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

The order where you apply middleware matters, if you don't apply to middleware to some routes, define that routes before applying the middleware.

In the following example, the /api/example route will not hit the middleware since it is before applying the middleware. But /api will hit.

```
// Define a route on the router
router.get('/example', (req, res) => {
    res.send('I will NOThit middleware');
});

// Apply the middleware to the router
router.use(routerMiddleware);

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('I will hit the middleware');
});

// Mount the router on the app
app.use('/api', router);
```

Comment: Diana did you try this answer?